# Display value as amount and also only display one cell label once using Javascript

Tags: javascript

Sorry if the heading is a little misleading.

I have a `webgrid` which at the bottom of the table I have JavaScript witch adds a 'Totals' row to it.

This row is displaying fine and the totals are correct, well sort of.  I hav e2 issues with my JavaScript and I cant figure out how to fix them as I am quite new to JavaScript.

**First issue**

When a cell it empty its displaying the word 'Totals'.  This is correct for the first cell as I want the field label but I don't want it displayed in all my other empty cells.

**Second issue**

My values are amounts (GBP) but some cells are displaying more than 2 decimal places.

**My JavaScript is**

```
var grid = document.getElementById("clientlisttable");
var total = 0;
var row = grid.insertRow();

if(grid.rows.length > 1)
{
    for (var i = 0; i < grid.rows[1].cells.length; i++)
    {
        var cell = row.insertCell(i);
        if (grid.rows[1].cells[i].innerHTML.indexOf("£") > -1)
        {
            for (var y= 1; y < grid.rows.length-3; y++)
            {
                total = total + parseFloat(grid.rows[y].cells[i].innerHTML.replace("£","").replace(",",""));
            }
            cell.innerHTML = "£" + total;
            cell.className = "clientlisttotals";
            total = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            cell.innerHTML = "Totals";
            cell.className = "clientlisttotals";
        }
    }
}

$('tbody').append(row);
```

Just curious also, if there's a way to remove the table class.  The table class this sits in is a table-hover but on this row I don't want the hover to work, is there a way to also remove this for this row?

I have also tried using `.toFixed(2)` but I get an error when running it, unless I am using it wrong.

I want to do this in JavaScript only please and could you please provide examples of the changes I need to make.

**I have managed to resolve the decimal place issue by adding `.toFixed(2)` to the row `cell.innerHTML = "£" + total.toFixed(2);`. This issue is now resolved.
Just need help with the duplication please and also how to format my value as an amount with ',' in it**

**I have now managed to resolve the comma issue by updating `cell.innerHTML = "£" + total.toFixed(2).replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, "$1,");`. This issue is now also resolved.
Just need help with the duplication please**

Comment: can you make a fiddle ?

Comment: `(3.14159).toFixed(2)` result:  3.14 - Also `(3.14159)>>0` result:  3

Comment: You are adding Totaols in every cell.You can use cell[0] to add in only one cell

Comment: @Mohit can you please provide an example as I'm a little unsure of your comment, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code below fixes all the issues I raised in my initial post

```
var grid = document.getElementById("clientlisttable");
var total = 0;
var row = grid.insertRow();

if(grid.rows.length > 1)
{
    for (var i = 0; i < grid.rows[1].cells.length; i++)
    {
        var cell = row.insertCell(i);
        if (grid.rows[1].cells[i].innerHTML.indexOf("£") > -1)
        {
            for (var y= 1; y < grid.rows.length-2; y++)
            {
                total = total + parseFloat(grid.rows[y].cells[i].innerHTML.replace("£","").replace(",",""));
            }
            cell.innerHTML = "£" + total.toFixed(2).replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, "$1,");
            cell.className = "clientlisttotals";
            total = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            if (cell.cellIndex != "0"){
                cell.innerHTML = "";
                cell.className = "clientlisttotals";
            }
            else{
                cell.innerHTML = "Totals";
                cell.className = "clientlisttotals";
            }
        }
    }
}
```